# ASP.NET MVC3 The column cannot contain null values

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am a new to ASP.NET MVC4 and stuck with something very basic.

I have this model

```
public class Book
{
    [Key]
    public int BookID { get; set; }
    public string BookName { get; set; }
}
```

and a Publish view as

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Publish";
}
<h2>Publish</h2>

@using (@Html.BeginForm("Publish", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BookID);
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BookName);
    <input type="submit" />
}
```

And a Publish action method like this

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Publish(Book book)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _db.Books.Add(book);
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(book);
    }
```

I am using SQL Server Compact 4.0 database. _db is the DbContext instance.

I have a table *Books* with fields *BookID* and *BookName*. BookID is primary key. So very basic.

The problem is when I goto **Publish** view, enter a **BookID** and **BookName** in input fields and press Submit, I always get

***The column cannot contain null values. [ Column name = BookID,Table name = Books ] *** exception. The only way this works is when I make BookID also an Identity field in the table, that ofcourse I dont want currently.

What am I missing in this simple structure?

Comment: you should probably tag this question with the entity framework version you are using aswell, or if not EF, point out what _db is

Comment: Yes its Entity Framework with version 4.3.6

Comment: Try this as an attribute to your BookID                              [Required, Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]

Comment: @emrenevayeshirazi thanks. This works now as intended. Can you please explain why? and do I have to place the DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None) on each of my primary key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[Required, Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]`

attribute should do the trick.

---

Or you can also do this in your `DbContext` class inside `OnModelCreating` method.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
      base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

      modelBuilder.Entity<Book>()
                   .Property(r => r.BookID) 
                   .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
}
```

Comment: Yes this works. but now I have to add this DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None) on all of my primary keys, which is I think pretty odd or this is how it works in ASP.NET ?

Comment: @Dandy You can also do it inside your DbContext class. And it related to EF not ASP.NET.